# iptables list line numbers script iptables-save -bash: number-rules: command not found

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, bash

I am trying to use a script for showing iptables line numbers from `iptables-save` command.

The script was taken from this site: https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2018-02-08-listing-iptables-rules-with-li/

And is as follows with `number-rules` name:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

state == 0 && /^-A/ {state=1; chain=$2; counter=1; printf "\n"}
state == 1 && $2 != chain {chain=$2; counter=1; printf "\n"}
!/^-A/ {state=0}
state == 1 {printf "[%03d] %s\n", counter++, $0}
state == 0 {print}
```

When I execute it throws below error:

> ```
> root@ergesttstsrv:~# iptables -S | number-rules
> -bash: number-rules: command not found
> ```

I checked `awk` with

```
root@ergesttstsrv:~# which awk
/usr/bin/awk
```

And changed the first line of the script
from `#!/bin/awk -f` to `/usr/bin/awk -f` , but still the same error.

Is there a better way of doing this without the `iptables -nv -L --line-numbers` or what is the error on the script?
Note I'm quite new with bash.

Comment: You need to make sure `number-rules` is executable and then need to use `./` to execute it from the current working directory (as it's not in your path) - so `iptables -S | ./number-rules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `number-rules` is executable and then need to use `./` to execute it from the current working directory, as that's not in your path - so `iptables -S | ./number-rules`

Comment: I made it executable and execute as you posted and it worked like a charm. Thanks